# How to solve this trigger error while trying to insert? oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a sp and a trigger, the trigger is supposed to call the procedure after I insert into the users table so I can create a new session user, but when I try to insert, I get the following errors:

- ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger ORA-06512: at "SQL_VNNKBUUOCEZLLPHWSSGEFNOQE.CREAR_USUARIO", line 10
- ORA-06512: at "SQL_VNNKBUUOCEZLLPHWSSGEFNOQE.TRG_INSERT_USUARIO", line 2
- ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

This is my sql code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE crear_usuario(
    p_nombre_de_usuario IN VARCHAR2,
    p_correo IN VARCHAR2,
    p_contrasenia IN VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER ' || p_nombre_de_usuario || ' IDENTIFIED BY ' || p_contrasenia;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_insert_usuario
AFTER INSERT ON usuario
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
crear_usuario(:NEW.nombre_de_usuario, :NEW.correo, :NEW.contrasenia);
END;
```

The weird thing is that I don't have any commit

Comment: DDL is probably doing the commit.  You can't "undo" DDL from a trigger, so what happens if the insert requires a rollback?  Try adding the AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION pragma to the procedure.

Comment: Either way, this looks like a risky proposition.  What happens if the same user is inserted twice?

Comment: Any advice on how to overcome the error is a way to shoot OP in their foot. Just don't do this and describe what do you want to achieve. Commit is caused by any syntactically valid DDL command: `create user ` in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, you should avoid trigger in this scenario. Do *everything* in a stored procedure.

BTW, what caused commit in a trigger: it was a DDL, it performs implicit commit right before and right after the DDL statement.

Can you commit in a trigger at all? Sure you can, if you make it an autonomous transaction, but - as I said - I wouldn't do that.

---

Here's an example of what you might do; code should be ran by user who has privilege that isn't that common - `create user`.

Table that contains users: of course, storing passwords as plain text is plain wrong, but that's just a simple example.

```
SQL> create table users
  2    (user_id     number generated always as identity primary key,
  3     username    varchar2(30) unique,
  4     password    varchar2(30)
  5    );

Table created.
```

Procedure: inserts a row into the table if it doesn't exist, and - if row was inserted - creates user:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_create_user
  2    (p_username in varchar2,
  3     p_password in varchar2
  4    ) as
  5  begin
  6    insert into users (username, password)
  7    select p_username, p_password
  8    from dual
  9    where not exists (select null
 10                      from users u
 11                      where u.username = p_username
 12                     );
 13    if sql%rowcount = 1 then
 14      execute immediate 'create user ' || p_username || ' identified by ' || p_password;
 15    end if;
 16  end;
 17  /

Procedure created.
```

Let's try it:

```
SQL> exec p_create_user('littlefoot', 'whatever');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From users;

   USER_ID USERNAME                       PASSWORD
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
         1 littlefoot                     whatever
```

Can I insert the same user again? No:

```
SQL> exec p_create_user('littlefoot', 'whatever');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From users;

   USER_ID USERNAME                       PASSWORD
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
         1 littlefoot                     whatever
```

A different user?

```
SQL> exec p_create_user('bigfoot', 'whatever');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From users;

   USER_ID USERNAME                       PASSWORD
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
         1 littlefoot                     whatever
         2 bigfoot                        whatever
```

What if I try to connect as newly created user:

```
SQL> connect littlefoot/whatever@pdb1
ERROR:
ORA-01045: user LITTLEFOOT lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL>
```

Apparently, creating user isn't enough. It exists, but can't do anything. I presume you'll handle that later.